# Polymer.js <core-animation> causes Chrome crash

Tags: javascript, html, animation, polymer

I'm working with `Polymer.js` and trying to create an animation using Javascript, I've been racking my brain because I can't seem to get the animation to work.

I'm using (from my Bower.json):

```
"core-elements": "Polymer/core-elements#^0.5.1",
"paper-elements": "Polymer/paper-elements#^0.5.1",
"polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^0.5.1"
```

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vanxrice/jyddm4g4/) to show a simple example, interestingly it does not crash Firefox however the animation also does not work in Firefox.

Here is the relevant portion of the Javascript where I try to begin the animation:

```
function startAnimation(template, document) {
  var animationTarget = template.content.querySelector('#animationTarget');
  var animation = new CoreAnimation();
  animation.duration = '1500';
  animation.iterations = 'Infinity';
  animation.keyframes = [{
      'opacity': 1
  }, {
      'opacity': 0
  }];
  animation.target = animationTarget;
  //animation.play(); // Uncommenting crashes my Chrome 39.0.2171.99 (64-bit) tab
}
```

I might be interacting with templates in Polymer incorrectly, any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a way to tackle the problem yet? I'm faced with a similar situation at the moment.

Comment: Still haven't revisited this myself, I plan to try Polymer 1.x in the near future to see if this is still happening.

Comment: Ok, good idea, will get back to Polymer dev soon enough to see for myself also.